# QuickBooks API example shows usage of "curl" but it actually doesn't work or am I missing something

Tags: ruby, curl, redirect, oauth-2.0, quickbooks

According to [QuickBooks Ruby API documentation](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0#step-2-redirect-to-intuits-oauth-2-0-server), it provides an example of using `curl` to submit a POST request to the authorization url obtained from Step 1, but right underneath it, it shows that if the web application doesn't support browsers, to use Playground or a web component.

My question is – is it actually possible to use the curl command as shown in the example? If I take the exact URL and try to establish a POST request, I get the following results:

```
bash-3.2$ curl -X POST "https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2?client_id=[redacted]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&response_type=code&scope=com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting&state=be17472c59724eb46bfe2690"
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
bash-3.2$
```

Obviously it's trying to redirect to another URL, but the API documentation doesn't show the usage of the `-L` parameter to follow redirects. If I try to provide the `-L` parameter for `curl` to follow redirects, then I get the following response:

```
bash-3.2$ curl -X POST "https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2?client_id=[redacted]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&response_type=code&scope=com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting&state=be17472c59724eb46bfe2690" -L
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Bad Request</H1>
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;7&#46;2500e8ac&#46;1592267832&#46;14229c52
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Again, doesn't work even following redirects. If I append `-I` to the `curl` command, then I get the following:

```
bash-3.2$ curl -X POST "https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2?client_id=[redacted]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&response_type=code&scope=com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting&state=be17472c59724eb46bfe2690" -LI
HTTP/2 301
date: Tue, 16 Jun 2020 00:37:17 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 162
location: https://appcenter.intuit.com/app/connect/oauth2?client_id=[redacted]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&response_type=code&scope=com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting&state=be17472c59724eb46bfe2690
server: nginx
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
strict-transport-security: max-age=3156000; includeSubDomains; preload

HTTP/2 302
date: Tue, 16 Jun 2020 00:37:17 GMT
content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
content-length: 406
location: https://accounts.intuit.com/index.html?partner_uid_button=google&offering_id=Intuit.sbg-fms.ippdevx&redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Fappcenter.intuit.com%2Fapp%2Fconnect%2Foauth2%3Fclient_id%3D[redacted]%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dcom.intuit.quickbooks.accounting%26state%3Dbe17472c59724eb46bfe2690
server: nginx
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000
intuit_tid: 1-5ee8143d-29a68cec2ec922da5c6be528
x-spanid: ad76586b-a5ac-41bd-b2df-022148a5a78b
x-amzn-trace-id: Self=1-5ee8143d-3aa839e8b2cf25d846078238;Root=1-5ee8143d-29a68cec2ec922da5c6be528
x-dns-prefetch-control: off
x-download-options: noopen
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
cache-control: private,no-cache,no-store,pre-check=0,post-check=0,must-revalidate
expires: -1
pragma: no-cache
set-cookie: hosted-shell=%7B%22clientId%22%3A%22a4676677-5191-4eca-873e-34a04b5b1dd4%22%7D; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 14 Jun 2030 00:37:17 GMT; Secure
vary: Accept, Accept-Encoding
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
strict-transport-security: max-age=3156000; includeSubDomains; preload

HTTP/2 411
server: AkamaiGHost
mime-version: 1.0
content-type: text/html
content-length: 223
expires: Tue, 16 Jun 2020 00:37:17 GMT
date: Tue, 16 Jun 2020 00:37:17 GMT
```

If I take the same URL and request it via a web browser, then it just takes me to the redirect callback URL as it's supposed to. I can't figure out why `curl` isn't doing the same thing. I don't understand what it means by "web component" if I can't even replicate the same thing via curl. I also have another web module that I'm using for GET and POST requests, and they're bringing me to an HTTP200 but not the callback URL.

Any idea how I could accomplish getting this authorization token from the redirect callback URL like it does in the web browser? Here's another example of me trying to do this via the web component in the Ruby script:

```
[3] pry(#<QuickBooksAPI>)> grant_url
=> "https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2?client_id=[redacted]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&response_type=code&scope=com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting&state=be17472c59724eb46bfe2690"
[4] pry(#<QuickBooksAPI>)> response = WebRequest.new.get_request(grant_url)
=> #<Net::HTTPMovedPermanently 301 Moved Permanently readbody=true>
[5] pry(#<QuickBooksAPI>)> response['Location']
=> "https://appcenter.intuit.com/app/connect/oauth2?client_id=[redacted]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&response_type=code&scope=com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting&state=be17472c59724eb46bfe2690"
[6] pry(#<QuickBooksAPI>)> response = WebRequest.new.get_request(response['Location'])
=> #<Net::HTTPFound 302 Found readbody=true>
[7] pry(#<QuickBooksAPI>)> response['Location']
=> "https://accounts.intuit.com/index.html?partner_uid_button=google&offering_id=Intuit.sbg-fms.ippdevx&redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Fappcenter.intuit.com%2Fapp%2Fconnect%2Foauth2%3Fclient_id%3D[redacted]%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dcom.intuit.quickbooks.accounting%26state%3Dbe17472c59724eb46bfe2690"
[8] pry(#<QuickBooksAPI>)> response = WebRequest.new.get_request(response['Location'])
=> #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
[9] pry(#<QuickBooksAPI>)> response.uri
=> #<URI::HTTPS https://accounts.intuit.com/index.html?partner_uid_button=google&offering_id=Intuit.sbg-fms.ippdevx&redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Fappcenter.intuit.com%2Fapp%2Fconnect%2Foauth2%3Fclient_id%3D[redacted]%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dcom.intuit.quickbooks.accounting%26state%3Dbe17472c59724eb46bfe2690>
```

This time it sends me to a 200 but it never actually sends me to the callback/redirect URL.

I'm just simply trying to complete step 2 but cannot do so without a browser it seems, even using "web components" and curl.

Am I just going to have to manually use OAuth Playground and continuously just refresh my token since my API is all backend and no front-end/user redirect, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

The OAuth grant flow needs your end user to grant your authenticate your application before you call API using access tokens. So here is what you process would look like

1. Present your user with a Connect to Intuit (or equivalent) button
2. User Clicks on the button and goes through authentication on intuit website (seems like the first bit of code you have inserted in your question. This cannot be automated)
3. Intuit redirects to the redirect url with a authorization_code
4. Rest is automated - Your browser or server takes the authorization_code from the url, combines it with a few other parameters and requests for an access_token
5. You can then continue to use the access_token to make your calls on behalf of the end user.

From Step3. onwards you can use curl to process all of it. Hope this helps :)

EDIT

No, In your case you would use OAuth differently. Using the Oauth Playground will take create an initial access_token for you. Steps 1-4 are taken care of.

Now you can use this token to authenticate all your API calls. However, the token will expire. So when you do get an expired response then you have to do a curl to fetch a new token using the info here...

https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0#refresh-the-token

Comment: Thanks. In my case, I am the end-user and I _always_ want to allow it access to my own QuickBooks account. Do I have to keep manually authorizing my application?

Comment: Thanks. Running into more issues now but will circle back to accept answer after trying solutino.